# Unusual Gas Usage?

Tags: solidity, truffle

Have the following function:

```
function _addBond(bytes32 alp, bytes32 bet) internal returns (uint256 id) {
    id = bonds.length / 2;
    bonds.push(alp);
    bonds.push(bet);
}
```

When I run this through my truffle-based gas analysis thing, it tells me that this function call is consuming **85788** gas

```
·----------------------------------------------------|---------------------------|--------------|----------------------------·
|        Solc version: 0.8.6+commit.11564f7e         ·  Optimizer enabled: true  ·  Runs: 1500  ·  Block limit: 6718946 gas  │
·····················································|···························|··············|·····························
|  Methods                                                                                                                   │
··························|··························|·············|·············|··············|··············|··············
|  Contract               ·  Method                  ·  Min        ·  Max        ·  Avg         ·  # calls     ·  usd (avg)  │
··························|··························|·············|·············|··············|··············|··············
|  BondDataExposed        ·  addBond                 ·          -  ·          -  ·       85788  ·           7  ·          -  │
..............................................................................................................................
```

Feel like this doesn't add up. 21k baseline + 40k for the two bytes32 sstores... what about the rest? 24k of gas is kind of a lot and I'm trying to figure out where it's going in this call. Am I doing something inefficient without realizing it?

Comment: What's `bonds`? _addBond is internal do you do anything else before calling it?

Comment: Nope, just created a dummy child contract 'BondDataExposed' to let me test addBond. Also, bonds is just an array of bytes32 in memory. I'll add this to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like calling the initial .push on an array not only initializes the actual thing you pushed from 0 to a nonzero value, but also initializes the .length property of the array from 0 to 1. Thus, first push has an extra 20k gas
Thus:

21k default

20k + 20k for two bytes32 sstore

20k for initializing array

81k in total. Rest may be accounted for by jumps and storage reads and such.

If you want to hyperoptimize this to get rid of a bit more gas, you might be able to do some assembly to increase array size by two and then save it normally -- might save you an increment. Potentially, that's also not how it works